# Recommended Method to simultaneously run two codeparts within a WPF Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a WPF application where the user enters a searchname/string and selects server1 or server2 based on checkboxes and then hits the search button. Based on the Checkbox selections it will query and search the first server or the second server but there is also the option of searching/querying both servers at once.
I have this currently setup inside the eventhandler with an if statement and an else statement but i will need to implement a third condition where both are selected.

Now within that third control statement I want both queries to be executed at the same time but I am not sure on what the best method of implementing this is.

Here is the code:

```
private void searchGzBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(usrBoxValue, pwdBoxValue, domainFuerNetCred);
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GzBoxValue)) && Handle(checkboxGz2010)) 
            {
                ListBox2010.Items.Clear();
                using (ClientContext clientctx = new ClientContext(url2010BoxValue))
                {

                    clientctx.Credentials = credentials; 
                    List selektierteListe = clientctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(comboBoxValue);
                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='GZ'/><Value Type='Text'>" + GzBoxValue + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='BaseName' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Name' /><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields></View>"; //Viewfields noch einbauen

                    ListItemCollection GFGZListe = selektierteListe.GetItems(query);
                    clientctx.Load(GFGZListe);
                    clientctx.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (ListItem item in GFGZListe)
                    {
                        ListBox2010.Items.Add("" +item["FileleafRef"]);
                    }
                    GFGZListePass = GFGZListe;
                }
            }
```

As mentioned previously this is directly followed by the else statement which basically is just a check to see if the other server checkbox is enabled and basically performs the same operation in terms of the clientctx.ExecuteQuery(); only difference being that the query is slightly different and the variable names are slightly different (for storing the results).

Now what if i need both of these CamlQuery's to run at the same time? Should i be looking at the Parallel.Invoke implementation? Or Tasks and Threading? What is the recommended course of action here?

Essentially i want:

1) Check if both checkboxes are checked
2) if they are execute both queries at the same time
3) Return the results

So if anyone has suggestions as to the best way in approaching this problem Id appreciate it.

Kind regards

Comment: What is the target .NET version and your Visual Studio version?

Comment: I have to use .NET 3.5 , Visual Studio is version 2010 but i have 2012 and 2013 available to me at a different office.

Comment: If you have to *target* .NET 3.5, it's very unfortunate you cannot use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx). You still can use `ExecuteQueryAsync` *or* `BackgroundWorker` *or* a low-level threading API like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SharePoint, there is a *naturally asynchronous* API for this, [`ExecuteQueryAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj168848%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
public override void ExecuteQueryAsync(
    ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler succeededCallback,
    ClientRequestFailedEventHandler failedCallback
)
```

First, you'd need to wrap it with [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a separate method (let's call it `ExecuteQueryTapAsync`) returning a `Task`, using `succeededCallback` and `failedCallback`. More info on that: [How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/19/9791857.aspx?Redirected=true).

Then you can run two queries in parallel like below. You'd need to make your button click handler `async`:

```
private async void searchGzBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // ... 

       // server1
       var query1 = ExecuteQueryTapAsync(clientctx);
       // ...

       // server2
       var query2 = ExecuteQueryTapAsync(clientctx);
       // ...

       // asynchronously await both results
       await Task.WhenAll(query1, query2);
       // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow i didnt know about the Client Object model having that method available. Thanks! I read your comment about .NET 3.5 not having the Task.Parallel method available. The AsyncQuery method you posted seems interessting enough and like a good opportunity to learn something new. I do have a strict deadline till friday so I might employ a simpler solution like Backgroundworkers if the need be. Need to read up on the TaskCompletionSource but you have provided me with great references and the tools to solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Orbital, no problem. You can use `AsyncQuery` without `BackgroundWorker`, it's already asynchronous. Use `succeededCallback`/`failedCallback` and call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` from there to continue execution on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to spawn two background threads.  This is the general idea:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    // ... run this block in a background thread

    ListItemCollection GFGZListe = selektierteListe.GetItems(query);
    clientctx.Load(GFGZListe);

    // return the result to the continuation block (below)
    return GFGZListe;
}).ContinueWith(task => {
    // handle results
    foreach (ListItem item in task.Result)
    {
        ListBox2010.Items.Add("" +item["FileleafRef"]);
    }
}, 
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());    // use the UI thread for the continuation
```

Just make sure not to put any UI-related stuff in the background thread, or you'll get a cross-thread access exception.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will use this/Backgroundworkers as a fallback method incase i am unable to implement the asynchronous query properly by friday. Appreciate the quick and concise response :)